# How to prevent transition and animation clash?

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox, css-animations

I'm working with CSS animations and transitions.

And here's the code:

```css
.heading {
    background-color: crimson;
    width: 40vw;
    width: 440px;

    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    padding: 10px;
}

.heading span {
    background-color: bisque;
    padding: 20px;

    transition: color 1s, transform 2s;
    color: transparent;
    transform: rotateX(180deg);
}


.heading:hover span {
    animation: show 2s linear;
    
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
    color: black;
}

#first_letter {
    animation-delay: 0.1s;
    transition-delay: 1.1s;
}

#second_letter {
    animation-delay: 0.3s;
    transition-delay: 0.9s;
}

#third_letter {
    animation-delay: 0.5s;
    transition-delay: 0.7s;
}

#fourth_letter {
    animation-delay: 0.7s;
    transition-delay: 0.5s;
}

#fifth_letter {
    animation-delay: 0.9s;
    transition-delay: 0.3s;
}

#sixth_letter {
    animation-delay: 1.1s;
    transition-delay: 0.1s;
}


@keyframes show {
    0% {
        transform: perspective(150px) rotateX(180deg);
        color: transparent;
    }

    50% {
        color: transparent;
    }

    to {
        color: black;
        transform: rotateX(0deg);
    }
}
```

```html
<h1 class="heading">
            <span id="first_letter">E</span>
            <span id="second_letter">F</span>
            <span id="third_letter">F</span>
            <span id="fourth_letter">E</span>
            <span id="fifth_letter">C</span>
            <span id="sixth_letter">T</span>
</h1>
```

Now if you hover over the heading, the animation starts from the left side elements (as the animation-delay is least there). But the transition-delay is least in the right side and therefore, it start to show effect from the right side.

Which messes it up all. What I want is, when hovered, only the animation should show effect from left to right but when we unhover the heading, only then transition should show the effect from right to left.

Also...

If you notice, when hovered, I rotated the span and changed the text color to black, but only rotation is happening in the transition effect. But if you don't add animation on hover, the color also shows the transition effect along with the rotation.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want to achieve?

Just reverse the `transition-delay` in your css.

```css
.heading {
    background-color: crimson;
    width: 40vw;
    width: 440px;

    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    padding: 10px;
}

.heading span {
    background-color: bisque;
    padding: 20px;

    transition: color 1s, transform 2s;
    color: transparent;
    transform: rotateX(180deg);
}


.heading:hover span {
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
    color: black;
}

#first_letter {
    animation-delay: 0.1s;
    transition-delay: 0.1s;
}

#second_letter {
    animation-delay: 0.3s;
    transition-delay: 0.3s;
}

#third_letter {
    animation-delay: 0.5s;
    transition-delay: 0.5s;
}

#fourth_letter {
    animation-delay: 0.7s;
    transition-delay: 0.7s;
}

#fifth_letter {
    animation-delay: 0.9s;
    transition-delay: 0.9s;
}

#sixth_letter {
    animation-delay: 1.1s;
    transition-delay: 1.1s;
    
}
@keyframes show {
    0% {
        transform: perspective(150px) rotateX(180deg);
        color: transparent;
    }

    50% {
        color: transparent;
    }

    to {
        color: black;
        transform: rotateX(0deg);
    }
}
```

```html
<h1 class="heading">
    <span id="first_letter">E</span>
    <span id="second_letter">F</span>
    <span id="third_letter">F</span>
    <span id="fourth_letter">E</span>
    <span id="fifth_letter">C</span>
    <span id="sixth_letter">T</span>
</h1>
```